# Extract ZIP file to memory (not disk)

Tags: c#, .net, zip

I need to extract a zip file to memory (not to the disk). I cannot save it to a directory, even temporarily.

Is there a way to extract a zip file just to memory, and perform "File" functions there?

I can't open the file as a file stream because this doesn't allow me to read the metadata (last write time, attributes, etc). Some but not all the file attributes can be read from zip entry itself but this is insufficient for my purposes.

I've been using:

```
using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(openFileDialog.FileName))  // Read files from the zip file
{
    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
    {
        if(entry.Name.EndsWith(".txt", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) // get .txt file
        {
            FileStream fs = entry.Open() as FileStream;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: [`ZipArchiveEntry.ExternalAttributes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchiveentry.externalattributes)? What other attributes do you need to access?

Comment: You can assume all attributes.

Comment: Use MemoryStream instead of FileStream.  After filling MemoryStream you need to set the position to zero before reading.

Comment: I'm surprised that your cast to FileStream succeeds. I don't see how that could be. Open returns a Stream from which you can read.

Answer (score 1):

The code below presents a way to get the file into memory as an array of strings, but it is unclear as to what file functions you are asking for. Other commenters have mentioned ExternalAttributes, which is OS dependent therefore it is relevant to have more information as to the problem space.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace StackOverflowSampleCode
{
    class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Validate the extension is correct
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entry"></param>
        /// <param name="ext"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        static bool validateExtension(ZipArchiveEntry entry, string ext)
        {
            return entry.Name.EndsWith(
                        ext,
                        StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Convert the entry into an array of strings
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entry"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        static string[] extractFileStrings(ZipArchiveEntry entry)
        {
            string[] file;
            // Store into MemoryStream
            using (var ms = entry.Open() as MemoryStream)
            {
                // Verify we are at the start of the stream
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                // Handle the bytes of the memory stream
                // by converting to array of strings
                file = ms.ToString().Split(
                    Environment.NewLine, // OS agnostic
                    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            }

            return file;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string fileName = "";

            using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(fileName))
            {
                foreach (var entry in archive.Entries)
                {
                    // Limit results to files with ".txt" extension
                    if (validateExtension(entry, ".txt"))
                    {
                        var file = extractFileStrings(entry);

                        foreach (var line in file)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(line);
                        }

                        Console.WriteLine($"Last Write Time: {entry.LastWriteTime}");
                        Console.WriteLine($"External Attributes: {entry.ExternalAttributes}");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```